# Should I use "then" or "flatMap" for control flow?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactor

So, I'm trying to work with Webflux and I've got a scenario "check if an object exists; if so, do stuff, else - indicate error".

That can be written in reactor as:

```
public Mono<Void> handleObjectWithSomeId(Mono<IdType> id){
    return id.
        flatMap(repository::exists). //repository.exists returns Mono<Boolean>
        flatMap(e -> e ? e : Mono.error(new DoesntExistException())). 
        then(
            //can be replaced with just(someBusinessLogic())
            Mono.fromCallable(this::someBusinessLogic) 
        );
}
```

or as:

```
public Mono<Void> handleObjectWithSomeId(Mono<IdType> id){
    return id.
        flatMap(repository::exists). //repository.exists returns Mono<Boolean>
        flatMap(e -> e ? e : Mono.error(new DoesntExistException())). 
        map(e -> this.someBusinessLogic()));
}
```

Let's assume that return type of `someBusinessLogic` cannot be changed and it has to be simple `void`, not `Mono<Void>`.

In both cases if the object won't exist, appropriate `Mono.error(...)` will be produced.

While I understand that `then` and `flatMap` have different semantics, effectively I get the same result. Even though in second case I'm using `flatMap` against its meaning, I get to skip `flatMap` and `fromCallable` in favor of simple `map` with ignored argument (that seems more readable). My point is, both apporaches have advantages and disadvantages when it comes to readability and code quality.

So, here's a summary:

Using then

- pros

  - is semantically correct
- cons

  - in many cases (like above) requires wrapping in ad-hoc Mono/Flux

Using flatMap

- pros

  - simplifies continued "happy scenario" code
- cons

  - is semantically incorrect

What are other pros/cons of both approaches? What should I take under consideration when choosing an operator?

I've found [this reactor issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/376) that states that there is not real difference in speed.

Answer (score 11):

**TL, DR:** If you care about the result of the previous computation, you can use `map()`, `flatMap()` or other `map` variant. Otherwise, if you just want the previous stream finished, use `then()`.

You can see a detailed log of execution for yourself, by placing an `.log()` call in both methods:

```
public Mono<Void> handleObjectWithSomeId(Mono<IdType> id) {
    return id.log()
             .flatMap(...)
             ...;
}
```

---

Like all other operations in Project Reactor, the semantics for `then()` and `flatMap()` are already defined. The context mostly defines how these operators should work together to solve your problem.

Let's consider the context you provided in the question. What `flatMap()` does is, whenever it gets an event, it executes the mapping function asynchronously.

[image: flatmap marble diagram]

Since we have a `Mono<>` after the last `flatMap()` in the question, it will provide the result of previous single computation, which we ignore. Note that if we had a `Flux<>` instead, the computation would be done for every element.

On the other hand, `then()` doesn't care about the preceding sequence of events. It just cares about the *completion* event:

[image]

That's why, in your example it doesn't matter very much which one you use. However, in other contexts you might choose accordingly.

You might also find the [Which operator do I need?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#which-operator) section Project Reactor Reference helpful.

Comment: Your explanation is very well phrased and I think some people will find it helpful, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. I do understand how both these operators work, I was just wondering about this specific case of Mono-based error. I'm just wondering now whether there is a difference when is onComplete called in case of then() and flatMap(), like if then() completes previous stream, while flatMap would wait for next stream to complete first.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by next or previous stream? If the `onComplete` is what you're after, diagrams describe the termination events.

Comment: If you're interested in error flow, both operations will emit an error event if there's an exception, or a `Mono.error(...)` is emitted by an operation. Any errors will be caught by the `onErrorXxxx()` handlers. 

In any case, I suggest you put a `log()` statement in the method, to actually see what's going on.